# スクレイピングで為替情報の取得を試みていますが、要素の指定で躓いています。

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

## 前提

閲覧頂きありがとうございます。

為替レートの情報を自動で取得したく
スクレイピングを試みています。

下記のサイトでCookieの同意をクリックした後、
「Amount you paid」の項目に入力するため要素の取得をしたいのですが、
要素が見つからずエラーとなります。

■対象ページ
https://usa.visa.com/support/consumer/travel-support/exchange-rate-calculator.html

```
!pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
!pip install webdriver_manager
from time import sleep

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

elem_ok_btn = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="CookieReportsBanner"]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]')
elem_ok_btn.click()

#エラー箇所↓↓
irame = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="input_amount_paid"]')
```

## 試したこと

iframeが使われているということで、
最終行を下記に変更しましたが、
input_amount_paid　が見つからないということで
エラーとなります。

```
browser.switch_to.frame('input_amount_paid')
iframe = browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'input')
```

↓エラーメッセージ
NoSuchFrameException: Message: input_amount_paid

打開策を探っておりますが上手くいかず、
該当のページは何か特殊な構造なのでしょうか？

解決策についてはご存知であれば
お知恵をお貸し頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: 開発者ツールで見ると`dm-calculator`というタグの中にJavaScriptのソースが短縮されて入っているようですが。その中の`#shadow-root (open)`の更に中にHTMLが定義されているようです。そうした名前から検索すると、こんな記事 [javascript で #shadow-root （shadowRoot） の中身をスクレイピングする](https://zenn.dev/atom/articles/750f9660f6a70a), [【Python・Selenium】shadow-rootを開く](https://www.automation-technology.info/index.php/2021/11/06/post-478/), [【Python Selenium】#shadow-rootのスクレイピング方法](https://marokoron.hatenablog.com/entry/2022/01/27/200000) が見つかるので、調べてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 念のため確認ですが、あくまでスクレイピングが目的 (目標) でしょうか？ / 為替情報の取得であれば、もっと簡単に API で取得する方法も考えられます。 https://fixer.io/ , https://exchangeratesapi.io/

Comment: ご教示頂いたshadow-rootを取得する方法で解決できました。
この度はご回答頂き、ありがとうございました。